# Select single column from a sub query returning multiple columns

Tags: mysql, vertica

This is my query

```
select *
from table  
where a in (select a,b,count(*) from table where b= 99991231 group by 1,2 having count(*) > 1)  ;

ERROR 4829:  Subquery has too many columns
```

I want to select those values of a where b's value is 99991231 and is repeated more than one

Comment: In subquery, `select a` is enough.

Comment: You are projecting three columns in your subquery, but comparing a single one of them in the IN clause. Select

Comment: Why would you want to use a subquery?

Comment: I need to select other columns including a

Answer (score 1):

Without subquery you can write it as

```
select a
from table 
where b= 99991231 
group by a
having count(*) > 1
```